# Loop cursor variable in DB2

Tags: db2

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE qqq ()

            P1: BEGIN
                Declare cID char(5) ;
                Declare cc char(5) ;
                Declare SQLSTATE char(5) default '00000' ;        
                declare stmt  varchar(1000) ;
                declare c1 cursor for s1 ;  


                set cid = 'b' ;
      
     
                Set stmt = 'select * from aaa where a = ?' ;
                prePare s1 from stmt ;


                open c1 using cid ;
                ins_loop :
                Loop
                   fetch c1 into cc ;
   
                    if SQLSTATE <> '00000' then LEAVE ins_loop ; end if ;
   
                    insert into bbb (aa) values ('3' || cc) ;
   
                end loop ins_loop;
                 close c1 ;
                commit ;
   
            END P1
```

After running,the table bbb is empty. IF it is correct, the table bbb has 2 rows. Because the query ( select * from aaa where a = 'b'  ) has 2 rows.

Comment: Not reproducible. Learn how to use a debugger to single-step through your code at run time and examine the variables.  Your symptom (no rows inserted) will happen if the cursor returns no data. Unless you are able to debug, then __things are not what they appear to be__

Comment: if there is more than 1 column in AAA and you really have a `select *` then probably sqlstate value is `01503` after fetch, which means you have to select  the column you want only and `LEAVE` only when `SQLSTATE` = 02000 (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sqlstate#rsttmsg__code01))

Comment: Why does not it show error (   SQLSTATE  ) when the scrip is running

Comment: there's no reason to use a cursor here.  You can directly insert the results of a select statement.  `insert into bbb (aa) select '3' concat column_name from aaa where a = cid;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get SQLSTATE = 01503, if your table contains more than 1 column. It's a warning (not an exception), so your SP proceeds its execution.
Either use `select column_name from ...` or modify the `SQLSTATE <> '00000'` condition appropriately instead.

P.S.: don't use `commit` in your SP unless it's really necessarily. It doesn't matter in this case, but it's better, when calling application manages transactions.